# How to show date box on pop up screen in jquery moblie

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am implementing date box in pop up screen in jquery mobile .is this possible to show date box in pop up screen? Because there is possibility of conflict theam because both have same theam.
Here is my code .I need to show date box in front of case date field.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/DtnYz/

```
<a href="" data-role="button" id="search">Search</a>
  <div data-role="popup" id="CaseInformationScreen" data-close-btn="none"  data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
                    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >

                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="Cancel">Cancel</a>
                        <h1>Case Information</h1>
                        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" id="AddButton">Add</a>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="content">
                        <div><img src="img/Documents.png"/></div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="text-12" style="text-align:top;margin-left: 0px;">Case Name:</label>
                            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h">
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="text-12" style="text-align:left;margin-left: 0px;" >Case Date:</label>
                            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseDate_h">
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on('click', '#search', function() {

     var d = new Date();

           var month = d.getMonth()+1;
           var day = d.getDate();
           var output = d.getFullYear() + '/' +
            ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
             ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;

$(".caseDate_h").val(output)
  $( "#CaseInformationScreen" ).popup( "open" )
});
```